# Angularjs and IScroll: ngClick doesn't work inside a scrollcontainer on iOS

Tags: angularjs, iscroll

Stumbled across this issues while testing on iOS simulator lately using angular 1.2 and IScroll 5 beta. Unfortunately I've currently no access to a physical iOS device.

Can anyone confirm this? Works on Android/chrome though.

Comment: my ng-click with iscroll is working .